# Создание библиотеки в OMF-формате через masm32

Tags: ассемблер, библиотеки, lib, masm32

Необходимо создать библиотеку и прогу, использующую эту библиотеку.
Если использовать `tlib` для компиляции библиотеки, всё ок, но нужно всё же сделать через `lib` (из masm32).

Компилер `ml` позволяет, задав опцию, `/omf` генерировать obj'и в OMF-формате, `link16` без проблем собирает их, а вот `lib`, собака, создаёт lib'ы в COFF-формате, даже если obj'и созданы как OMF (он их конвертирует в COFF).

Можно ли что-то с этим сделать, чтобы **использовать только средства masm32 для компиляции библиотеки в OMF-формате?**

**Ну или скомпилить DOS-прогу в COFF-формате?** Потому что сейчас ml ругается, якобы *`undefined symbol DGROUP`* в исходнике (там используются сокращённые точечные директивы `.model`, `.code` и т.п).

Comment: "Ну или..." - это уже другой вопрос. И проблема скорее всего не в формате объектных файлов. Ну и второе, вам действительно нужны библиотеки (lib)?

Comment: В любом случае опишите поподробнее что вы хотите сделать (желательно с [минимальным самодостаточным воспроизводимым примером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), тогда можно будет посмотреть, в чем проблема.

Comment: @insolor, примеры исходников см. тут: http://xk8.ru/files/lib_masm32.zip . Сначала запускается `_makelib.bat`, а потом `_compile.bat`. Будет ошибка. Если же использовать `_makelib_tasm.bat`, то будет всё ок.

Comment: Все еще интересней. Если скомпилировать lib в coff и просто закомментировать строки `mov ax,@data` и `mov ds,ax`, то перестает ругаться на `DGROUP`, но при линковке ругается, что `ABC.lib` - не валидная библиотека. Похоже на то, что `link16` не понимает `coff`.

Comment: @insolor, так я о том и говорю (что `link16` не понимает `coff`) :)) Вопрос в том, **можно ли как-то создавать lib'ы в `omf`-формате, используя средства `masm32`**?

Comment: в masm32 похоже нет. Можно поискать MASM 6.11 на просторах интернета, возможно в нем что-то такое есть. Но он только под DOS работает, насколько я помню.

Comment: **MASM 6.11/14** может, но под DOS – это да...